# Lower bound for maximal function which yields maximal function is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be Lebesgue integrable and $f$ is not identically zero (i.e., $m(\{x \mid f(x) \neq 0\}) >0$). Then there exist constant $C, R > 0$ such that $$\sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{m(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)| \, dy = (Mf)(x) \geq \frac{C}{|x|^n}$$ for $|x| > R$. This fact will show that $Mf$ is not integrable.

Can anyone give me a guide ? For the first assertion, I look at the proof of Weak-$(1,1)$ inequality which provide the upper bound for $Mf$. It seems that the proof related to a clever method of choosing a ball $B(x,r)$. I am not sure how to adapt it to prove this assertion. (If you have an easy way to prove, please suggest it !). For the non-integrability of $Mf$, I do not think that $$\frac{C}{|x|^n} \rightarrow \infty$$ if $|x| \rightarrow \infty$ and $x$ is bounded away from $0$. So I do not see why this inequality will help showing that $Mf$ is not integrable.

Comment: To show nonintegrability, just use polar coordinate, then you are integrating $\int_c^\infty \frac{1}{r} dr$

Comment: @JohnMa I do not quite sure $||f||_{L^1}$ means ?: I think that my question does not have this assumption, I am not sure if the solution provided in the link can be applied to my case.

Comment: $\|f\|_{L^1} = \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|$. Your $f$ is integrable, so this is finite. Divide by a constant, you have $\|f\|_{L^1} = 1$.